# How to Create a nested list using nested for loop?

Tags: python

```
    def remove_extras(self, paths, destination):
        # Delete all paths that does not include the destination
        destination_paths = []
        destination_path = []
        for path in paths:
            if destination in path:
                for router in path:
                    destination_path.append(router)
                destination_paths.append(destination_path)
        print(destination_paths)

        return destination_paths[1:]
```

why am I getting [[router, router, router, ....]] and not [[router, router, ...], [router, router, ...], .....]?

Comment: Hello Rozhyar, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide the input you used with remove_extras()? With the complete output if possible.

I cannot reproduce the output you show with the inputs I tried to put in.

Comment: Much simpler: `destination_paths = [list(path) for path in paths if destination in path]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without even knowing what you would like to achieve, the previous posted code was almost right.
Try this one here:

```
def remove_extras(self, paths, destination):
    destination_paths = []
    for path in paths:
        destination_path = []
        if destination in path:
            for router in path:
                destination_path.append(router)
    
        destination_paths.append(destination_path)
    
    return destination_paths
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you overlooked that you are appending routers to the same `destination_path` list object all the time - then after the inner for-loop you are appending the same `destination_path` list object multiple times to `destination_paths`.

Instead, you should move the definition of `destination_path` *inside* the *outer* for loop - the code would then look like this:

```py
    def remove_extras(self, paths, destination):
        # Delete all paths that does not include the destination
        destination_paths = []
        for path in paths:
            if destination in path:
                destination_path = []
                for router in path:
                    destination_path.append(router)
                destination_paths.append(destination_path)
        print(destination_paths)

        return destination_paths[1:]
```